# How to reduce quantity of an item in main table when it is being used in another table - django

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite, django-models

I am creating my model in Django and I have a many to many relationship between supplies and van kits. The idea is that an "item" can belong to many "van kits" and a "van kit" can have many " items. I created an intermediary model that will hold the relationship, but I am struggling to figure out a way to relate the quantity in the van kit table to the quantity in the main supplies table. For example, if I wanted to mark an item in the van kit as damaged and reduce the quantity of that supply in the van kit, I would also want to reduce the total count of that supply in the main "supplies" table until it has been replenished. I am thinking that maybe I'll have to create a function in my views file to carry out that logic, but I wanted to know if it could be implemented in my model design instead to minimize chances of error. Here's my code:

```
class supplies(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "supplies"
    # limit the user to selecting a pre-set category
    choices = (
        ('CREW-GEAR','CREW-GEAR'),
        ('CONSUMABLE','CONSUMABLE'),
        ('BACK-COUNTRY','BACK-COUNTRY')
        )
    supplyName = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False) # if they go over the max length, we'll get a 500 error
    category = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices = choices, blank=False)
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=False) # set up default
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True) # inputting price is optional
    def __str__(self):
        return self.supplyName

class van_kit(models.Model):
    supply_name = models.ManyToManyField(supplies, through='KitSupplies',through_fields=('vanKit','supplyName'), related_name="supplies")
    van_kit_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    vanName = models.ForeignKey(vans, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.van_kit_name


class KitSupplies(models.Model):
    supplyName = models.ForeignKey(supplies, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vanKit = models.ForeignKey(van_kit, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.supplyName)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Kit Supplies'
```

I am fairly new to django, I have to learn it for a class project so if my logic is flawed or if a better way to do it is obvious, please respectfully let me know. I'm open to new ways of doing it. Also, I've read through the documentation on using "through" and "through_fields" to work with the junction table, but I'm worried I may not be using it correctly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what the two different quantity fields mean. Should Supplies.quantity just be the sum of all the KitSupplies.quantity for that supply?

Comment: My intention was for the Supplies.quantity to be the total of that specific supply. So if I have two van kits named "van kit1" and "van kit2" respectively, and they both contain 2 pans, Supplies.quantity would report a quantity of 4. Each respective van kit would report a quantity of 2 instead.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to drop/remove the field `quantity` from your `supplies` model and just use a query to get the total quantity.

This would be a bit more expensive, as the query would need to be run each time you want to know the number, but on the other hand it simplifies your design as you don't need any update logic for the field `supplies.quantity`.

The query could look as simple as this:

```
>>> from django.db.models import Sum
>>> supplies_instance.kitsupplies_set.aggregate(Sum('quantity'))
{'quantity__sum': 1234}
```

You could even make it a property on the model for easy access:

```
class supplies(models.Model):
    ...

    @property
    def quantity(self):
        data = self.kitsupplies_set.aggregate(Sum('quantity'))
        return data['quantity__sum']
```

Comment: That looks like an interesting solution, I've never used "@property" before so I'll take some time and learn its capabilities. Thank you!